# What is most efficient way to plot a domain of convergence?

Tags: r, statistics

Say, you have a Newton Method algorithms with 2 parameters of interest(a,b).
And I would like to plot their domain of convergence with x-axis = a, y-axis = b. Is there a really fast and simple to do this??? Any suggestions?

My algorithm will basically converge for some values of a & b. If I input (a,b), it will return (the number of iterations , value of a that it converge to, value of b that it converge to). Right now, I am thinking of setting up a  for loop within another for loop, which run through all possible values of b first holding a fixed, and all possible values that a will converge holding b fixed.

However, my trouble is: how to identify whether a & b is converging or not. And is there a better way than using nested for loops????

Comment: Perhaps you could show a reproducible example of the kind of alogrithm you're referring to?

Comment: I'm imagining that you could discretize the problem fairly finely and compute all the gradients in a vectorized way ... ?

Comment: With a nice bit of code we could draw pretty pictures: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_fractal